# How to resolve overlay permissions need granted in react-native dev mode?

Tags: react-native, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

I've changed my Android device from Android 7.0 to Android 8.0 to run a react-native app on.  Previously adding the overlay permission in AndroidManifest allowed the app to run and display the developer menu on the device:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.simpleoffsetpro"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
</manifest>
```

But when I run the app on Android 8.0 I grant the permission that's prompted "Permit drawing over other apps". Then the app just shows a grey screen with notification - `Overlay permissions needs to be granted in order for react native apps run in dev mode`.

Device: Huawei P Smart - Android 8.0.0

Question:

How can you resolve overlay permissions needs to be  granted in react-native dev mode?

Package.json depedencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.3.5",
    "convert-units": "^2.3.4",
    "event-emitter": "^0.3.4",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.8.1",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "lodash": "^4.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "native-base": "2.0.12",
    "react": "~15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "~15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.42.0",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-dismiss-keyboard": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-floating-label-text-input": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-hide-with-keyboard": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-listener": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^1.0.11",
    "react-native-material-initials": "^0.0.12",
    "react-native-overlay": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.12.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-loop-symbol-ponyfill": "^2.2.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
    "standard-http-error": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^17.0.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^3.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.7.1",
    "fetch-mock": "^5.5.0",
    "istanbul": "1.0.0-alpha.2",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^17.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "~15.4.2",
    "react-native-mock": "~0.2.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android oreo is [only supported](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/15601) from RN 0.51 + , update your react native, the latest version is 0.58, and the new version 0.59 is gonna bring hooks to react native 7u7

Comment: I will try upgrading. Will the app still work with previous target versions of Android on RN 0.51 + ?

Comment: Yeah, i would suggest using react native versions based on the changes that are made by looking at the changelog https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md . As soon as 0.59 is out believe me i'm switching to that version

Answer (score 0):

That line should look like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

But it's not normally something you should have to mess with.